# JavaFX distance between two circle and keep updating property

Tags: text, javafx, properties, distance

For assignment, I created 2 draggable circle and connect them with line with javaFX.

I need add text which calculate distance between two circle (or length of line) and that text need to keep updating when I drag circles, but that's where I stuck

```
    Circle circle1 = new Circle();
    circle1.setCenterX(40);
    circle1.setCenterY(40);
    circle1.setRadius(10);
    Circle circle2 = new Circle();
    circle2.setCenterX(120);
    circle2.setCenterY(150);
    circle2.setRadius(10);
    Line line = new Line ();

    line.startXProperty().bind(circle1.centerXProperty());
    line.startYProperty().bind(circle1.centerYProperty());
    line.endXProperty().bind(circle2.centerXProperty());
    line.endYProperty().bind(circle2.centerYProperty());

    circle1.setOnMousePressed(mousePressEventHandler);
    circle1.setOnMouseDragged(mouseDragEventHandler);
    circle2.setOnMousePressed(mousePressEventHandler);
    circle2.setOnMouseDragged(mouseDragEventHandler);
```

it's my two circles and line, and I tried

```
 Text distance = new Text();
 distance.textProperty().bind(circle1.centerXProperty()-circle2.centerXProperty() . . .);
```

However, as you know as, I can't normally calculate Property value, and I have no idea how should I do it.

Comment: This is a similar to a [question on JavaRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/662710/JavaFX/java/Making-streets-JavaFX-cool-rhyme) (though that similar question is a bit more complex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a DoubleProperty

```
DoubleProperty distanceProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
```

and a ChangeListener in which you calculate the distance

```
ChangeListener<Number> changeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

  Point2D p1 = new Point2D(circle1.getCenterX(), circle1.getCenterY());
  Point2D p2 = new Point2D(circle2.getCenterX(), circle2.getCenterY());
  distanceProperty.set(p1.distance(p2));

};
```

assign the listener

```
circle1.centerXProperty().addListener( changeListener);
circle1.centerYProperty().addListener( changeListener);
circle2.centerXProperty().addListener( changeListener);
circle2.centerYProperty().addListener( changeListener);
```

and bind the distanceProperty to the text

```
Text text = new Text();
text.textProperty().bind(distanceProperty.asString());
```

Comment: Use [`Bindings.createDoubleBinding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createDoubleBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-). That way you can get rid of the repetitive code for adding the listener to the properties...